# Update a line in a text file from another form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a  `form` that has MenuScripts (top-levels and second-levels).

The problem that I am having is one of the second-levels is "Add" which brings you to another `form`. This `form` has a button 'Record' and `textboxes`. This form allows the user to input data and when the record button is clicked, the inputted data is written to a text file.

Back to the first form. Another second-level MenuScript is "Update" which brings the user to the same `form` as "Add"; but first, the user has to click an item within a `listbox` to proceed.

How do I get the data from the selected item to appear in the appropriate `textboxes` and how do I get the 'Record' button to update data instead of thinking it is only an add-data button?

Also, if someone can give me some pointers on making sure the user selects an item within the `listbox` would definitely be a plus!

Unfortunately, I cannot add images since my reputation is too low.

[Here is a visual representation of my ultimate goal](http://www.flickr.com/photos/83812754@N07/7674806270/in/photostream)

Comment: A full answer should include a small program! I guess you have a class to describe each record (with a ToString() override that returns the title to be displayed in the ListBox). Just add a property to your forms where the caller set the record itself (or a file path) and (for example) in the Show event of the Form read that data and fill the textboxes. To disable menu items you may use Application.Idle event to set the MenuItem.Enabled property to false when the ListBox.SelectedIndex is -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the control in another form, you could prefix the formname to the control name(name of the control in the other form).

Example:

```
Form2.TextBox1.Text = "Hey, this is the second form"
```

To check whether an item is selected, you could do this way:

```
    If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select an item")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Thanks for selecting an item")
    End If
```

Or, this way:

```
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select an item")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Thanks for selecting an item")
    End If
```